# OpenGL 3 required, but it is present

Tags: windows-7, opengl

I'm trying to install [DIALux EVO 5.1](http://www.dial.de/DIAL/en/dialux/download/dialux-evo.html) but when I try to run it raises an exception noting that "OpenGL3 is required", see bellow:

[image: Error OpenGL3.0 required]

When I run a diagnosis tool it shows that OpenGL3.0 is 100% supported by my graphic card, see:

[image: OpenGL Diagnosis]
[image: OpenGL Diagnosis2]

What else could I do? Is it possible that any driver update could solve this issue?

System Information:

- Windows 7 64 bit
- VAIO PCG61111-x

Comment: Have you aleady asked on http://www.dial.de/DIAL/en/dialux/support.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it does say OpenGL 3.0 is required, it most certainly does not say it's missing. It simply states your graphics card doesn't meet the requirements.

On the [download page](http://www.dial.de/DIAL/en/dialux/download.html), it's easy to see the problem:

> OpenGL 3.0 graphics card
>   (*1 GB RAM*)

(emphasis mine)

According to your diagnostic tool, your ultra low end card doesn't have any dedicated memory at all.